# Android studio can't change color of title background in my custom dialog

Tags: android

I have a **Custom Dialog** and I'm trying to change the background color of the title bar, but it doesn't work.

This is my `styles.xml`

```
<style name="WindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">@color/PaleBlue</item>
</style>    

<style name="availabilityDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
</style>
```

I apply it as a theme to an activity in my manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".activities.ChangeAvailabilityActivity"
          android:theme="@style/availabilityDialog">
</activity>
```

The picture below shows the result

[image]

The color remains black/grey. I have tried different colors, setting `actionBarStyle` and `windowTitleStyle` to `WindowTitleBackground` etc. No luck.

Comment: show your custom dialog code please.

Comment: The availabilityDialog is my custom dialog, the picure displays it. I have no code for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

in your res/values/styles:

```
 <style name="custom_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/dialog_title_style</item>
  </style>

<style name="dialog_title_style" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/black</item> //change background color here
    <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
</style>
```

And use it as:

```
Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this,R.style.custom_dialog);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_dialog_layout);
dialog.setTitle("Example");
```

Comment: I edited my question, I am starting a an activity and applying my style as it's theme in the manifest. I tried using this soloution anyhow and it gave me a java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

Comment: if u are showing the dialog in an Activity you can apply separate style for the dialog..like i added

Comment: you need to add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` as your theme in activity instead of `android:theme="@style/availabilityDialog"`

Comment: I tried using <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground</item>
again as you said and now it worked all of a sudden, not sure what I did wrong the first time but it seems to work now. Thanks